# plotting histograms of the columns of a matrix (Stata 12)

Tags: matrix, histogram, stata

Working in Stata12, I need to plot 5 histograms, one for each column of the matrix `MAT`, where:

```
mata: MAT = uniform(1000, 5)
```

I understand that one possibility is to use `mm_histogram()` for obtaining the center, the width and the density of each interval of the histogram. For the first column we have:

```
mata: HIST_DAT = mm_histogram(MAT[.,1])
```

But then I do not know how to proceed for plotting the data (either in Stata or in Mata).

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

**EDIT**:
The question is also present at [Statalist archive](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-07/msg00204.html)

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2013-07/msg00204.html For strong opinions that such cross-posting obliges you to update all forums you use see http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/941/posting-same-question-on-other-statistics-forums-in-addition-to-cross-validated

Comment: Thank you very much, I was unaware of cross-posting. Kind regards, SL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, the code for plotting the histograms relative to `MAT` columns is:

```
clear all
set obs 1000

mata:

  // Mata matrix of results 
  MAT = uniform(500, 5)

  // generates Stata variables from within Mata
  Stata_vars = st_addvar("float", ("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5"))

  // stores MAT columns in the first 500 obs. of the Stata variables
  st_store((1::rows(MAT)), Stata_vars, MAT)  

end
```

Then we just need to type:

```
hist(V1)
```

for `V1` or any other `V2-V5` newly-created Stata variable.

Comment: It is still not fully clear to me how to proceed when the number of observations of the Stata dataset is different from the rows of the starting matrix.

Comment: Number of observations >= number of rows: no problem. Number of rows > number pf observations: you would need to `set obs` to the larger number first.

Comment: Thanks, just a last suggestion. Suppose `MAT` has 500 rows only. Instead of doing `missing = J(1000-rows(MAT), 5, .)` and then `MAT = MAT \ missing`, is there a more direct way for storing `MAT`? (maybe directly from within `st_store()`?).

Comment: Naturally. `st_store((1::500), Stata_vars, MAT)` or any other way of using  500 of the observations.

Answer (score 3):

There is one simple answer: copy your matrix column to a Stata variable and use `histogram`. Anything else will just be roundabout or approximate.

It's difficult to see what's central to this question, but if the interest is plotting histograms of random numbers, it is a lot easier to create them as variables in Stata:

```
 . set obs 500 
 . gen y = runiform()
 . histogram y
```